# Some examples of $I=(0,1)$ and $Q(I)$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $I=(0,1)$ and $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $2$.

(i) Find a polynomial like $Q$ such that $Q(I)$ is an open interval.

( Is $Q(x)=x^2 $ correct? Does that cover $(0,1)$ entirely? )

(ii) Find a polynomial like $Q$ such that $Q(I)$ is a half-opened interval.

(iii) Find a polynomial like $Q$ such that $Q(I)$ is a closed interval.

The problem is that the solution has to be a polynomial ... it has to be from degree $2$... I can't just write an arbitrary function with many formulas for each part of the domain ... I don't know a general method for solving this type of questions ...

Comment: If I gave you a polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ with $a>0$, would you be capable to find for what $x$ it attains its minimum?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli with derivation, yes ... but how is this useful ?

Comment: Well, because if $x_{m}\in I$, then $Q(I)=[m,\alpha)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli all right, that doesn't help with (iii) though, does it?  Is (iii) impossible?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Of course it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

For (i) your answer is correct (just notice that $x^2 = y$ has a unique solution $x \in (0,1)$ for every $y \in (0,1)$).

For (ii) use $Q(x) = (x - \frac 1 2)^2$ and notice that $Q((0,1)) = [0, \frac 1 4)$.

For (iii) there is no possibility, but the reasoning is slightly convoluted. Assume that such a $Q$ exists. Since $Q$ is a polynomial, it may be extended to the whole $\Bbb R$. Let then $[a,b] = Q(I)$ and $[c,d] = Q(\bar I)$ where $\bar I = [0,1]$. Since $I \subset \bar I$ we shall have $[a,b] \subseteq [c,d]$. Notice now that

$$[c,a) \cup (b,d] = [c,d] \setminus [a,b] = Q(\bar I) \setminus Q(I) \subseteq Q(\bar I \setminus I) = Q(\{0,1\})$$

and since $Q(\{0,1\})$ is made up of at most 2 points, it follows that it cannot contain intervals, therefore $c=a$ and $b=d$, so that $Q(\bar I) = Q(I)$.

Let $u = Q(0)$ and $v = Q(1)$. Since $u,v \in [a,b]$ and $Q(I) = [a,b]$ it follows that there exist $r,s \in I$ such that $Q(r) = u$ and $Q(v) = s$.

Is it possible that $r=0$? No, because in that case we would have $0$ a double root of $Q(x) - u$, meaning that $Q(x) = ax^2 + u$ and it is easy to see that such a polynomial does not transport $(0,1)$ onto a closed interval. Therefore, $r \ne 0$.

With exactly the same type of argument, one proves that $s \ne 1$.

Let now $Q(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ with $a \ne 0$.

Since $Q(0) = Q(r)$, we have that $c = ar^2 + br + c$, which means that $r(ar + b) = 0$ and, since we have shown that $r \ne 0$, it follows that $ar + b = 0$.

Since $Q(1) = Q(s)$, we have that $a+b+c = as^2 + bs + c$, which means that $(s-1) [a(s+1) + b] = 0$ and, since we have shown that $s \ne 1$, it follows that $a(s+1) + b = 0$.

Subtracting one relation from the other, we get that $0 = a(s+1) + b - (ar + b) = a(s+1-r)$ and, since $a \ne 0$, we get that $r-s = 1$. But this is not possible, because $r,s \in I = (0,1)$ which implies that $r-s < 1$. The fact that we have reached a contradiction shows that no such $Q$ exists.

---

It is worth noting that the fact that $Q$ has degree $2$ is crucial: situation (iii) becomes possible if we allow $Q$ to have degree $3$, for instance: just take $Q(x) = x^3 - x$ and $I = (-1, 1)$. Notice that the extrema of $Q$ are $\frac 2 {3 \sqrt 3}$ and $-\frac 2 {3 \sqrt 3}$, reached in the points $-\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$ and, respectively, $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$, and that $Q(I) = [-\frac 2 {3 \sqrt 3}, \frac 2 {3 \sqrt 3}]$.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, any polynomial with $-\frac{b}{2a}\in (0,1)$ will provide an explicit example for (ii).

For (iii), let $Q$ be a polynomial of degree $2$, and let $J$ be an interval such that $Q'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in J$. Then, $Q$ is strictly monotone on $J$ and, since $Q(J)$ is an interval, $Q(J)$ must be an open interval: you can't send a set without a minimum or a maximum to a set with either a minimum or a maximum via a strictly monotone function.

Consider $J=I\setminus\{x_m\}$, where $x_m$ is the only zero of $Q'(x)$ in $\Bbb R$. If $x_m\notin I$, $Q(I)$ is an open interval. If $x_m\in I$, we have the disjoint union of open intervals $J=I_1\cup I_2$ and $Q(I)=Q(I_1)\cup Q(I_2)\cup\{Q(x_m)\}$. But this is the union of two open intervals and a singleton, which can never be $[a,b]$